# Truncate a date in Postgres (latest version)

Tags: database, postgresql

I have different timestamps within my posgres db. With timestamp I mean unix time since 1970 saved as bigint.

Now I need to get the timestamp since 1970 striped down to days. For instance: 1469059200000 (Today: 2:00 am should become 1469052000000 (Today: 00:00 am)

I've tried this in pgadmin

```
Select date_trunc('day', rp.timestamp) from rollup_days as rp
```

but just got this error. ERROR:  function date_trunc(unknown, bigint) does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `bigint` is not "a timestamp", so you must convert the number to a date before you can apply `date_trunc()` on it:

```
Select date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(rp.timestamp)) 
from rollup_days as rp;
```

To convert the timestamp back to a bigint, use `extract()`

```
Select extract(epoch from date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(rp.timestamp)))
from rollup_days as rp;
```

Comment: Lol. Just found that out a few seconds ago. What is missing now is a way of transforming it back into the same format I had before (unix time since 1970 as bigint)

Comment: @Christian: see may edit. Btw: `timestamp` is a horrible name for a column. And why don't you store that as a real `timestamp`?

Comment: wtf -> Select extract(epoch from date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(rp.timestamp))) as timestamp_converted, timestamp from instana.rollup_days as rp <- This returns the SAME timestamp twice.